# Metaclass inheritance in Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, django, oop, inheritance, metaclass

I have following sample code for Python 2.7:

```
class MetaA(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print('MetaA::__new__')
        print('CLS:' + str(cls))
        print('Name:' + name)
        print('============================')
        return super(MetaA, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaA


class MetaB(type(A)):
    pass


class SomeMixin(A):
    pass


class B(A):
    __metaclass__ = MetaB


class C(SomeMixin, B):
    pass
```

After executing it I have such output:

```
MetaA::__new__
CLS:<class '__main__.MetaA'>
Name:A
============================
MetaA::__new__
CLS:<class '__main__.MetaA'>
Name:SomeMixin
============================
MetaA::__new__
CLS:<class '__main__.MetaB'>
Name:B
============================
MetaA::__new__
CLS:<class '__main__.MetaA'>
Name:C
============================
MetaA::__new__
CLS:<class '__main__.MetaB'>
Name:C
============================
```

The thing is when `class C` defined, at first method `__new__` is invoked for metaclass `MetaA` (base one) and then for metaclass `MetaB` invoked.

If I change the order of mixin and inherit class in my class C like this

```
class C(B, SomeMixin):
```

the output is following:

```
MetaA::__new__
CLS:<class '__main__.MetaA'>
Name:A
============================
MetaA::__new__
CLS:<class '__main__.MetaA'>
Name:SomeMixin
============================
MetaA::__new__
CLS:<class '__main__.MetaB'>
Name:B
============================
MetaA::__new__
CLS:<class '__main__.MetaB'>
Name:C
============================
```

Method `__new__` for metaclass `MetaA` not invoked in this case, only for metaclass `MetaB`.

If I run almost same code in Python 3, despite of inheritance order in `class C`, method `__new__` will be invoked only for metaclass `MetaA`.

Could someone please explain why this happens and what was changed in Python 3 in terms of this behavior?

Thanks!